# On Ubuntu 18.04, RawTherapee freezing entire computer

Tags: 18.04, debugging

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a HP elite 7100 microtower, Intel i7 with 8 GB RAM. Works great, except when I use RawTherapee it freezes the entire computer. I usually have Google Chrome streaming music and gThumb running when this happens. I am not sure if a particular function in RawTherapee is  causing this issue. It may be when I try to export, but I am not sure.

Comment: Try running it without any other apps open?

Comment: I will try running by itself and pay more attention to exactly what is going on.

Comment: I believe it was Wallpaper downloader causing the problem;it would freeze the computer when I tried to set the photo as wallpaper,even though wallpaper downloader was not running at the time.Uninstalled  wallpaper downloader ,problem solved.

Comment: That's great! I'm glad you've got your problem solved.